# How do I do Loops to run a regression for multiple periods

Tags: r

So I have this dataset, and I need to run a regression for every 60 periods, I understand how to run the regression and have been trying to repeat the regression for every 60 periods and have the betas in a matrix. But I don't quite understand how to get R to move down in my data to run a new regression on a seperate list of data points.

This is my current code, you can see that I attempted to engineer the dataset in a way to get it along but I know its wrong, I just don't know how to proceed. Thanks.

```
data.dt <-read.csv("Assignment 1.CSV")

## First install the AER package (Packages, Install, AER) and call it up for use:
library(AER)
library(texreg)

##(2) Estimating CAPM Betas and Idiosyncratic Volatilities
CAPM <-matrix(nrow=100, ncol=2)
n <- 0

for (i in (1+60*n):(60+60*n){
eqn1 <- summary(lm(Returns.SMALL.LoBM~Mkt.RF, data=data.dt))
CAPM[i,1] <-eqn1$coefficients[2,1]
CAPM[i,2] <-eqn1$coefficients[2,2]
n <-n+1
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you could share a reproducible subset of your data set.